# how to use Vue with wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been learning wordpress and I'm trying to figure out how to use Vue with wordpress. I'm currently just trying to do the basic CDN vue or link the vue file so that I can do basic things to interact with my page. Not worrying about vue components or anything that will be way more work if it works at all with wordpress lol.

Is this even possible to do with wordpress? Think the basic js fiddle's for vue where your js file interacts directly with the page (not components compiled and stuff). I just want to do simple things like make my navbar change color if its not at the top, basic stuff with buttons, etc. I really like using vue so if I can I'd rather use vue than have to make straight js to do these things. But I cant figure out how to get it set up.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, you can look at codepen and jsfiddle examples that show you how to use uncompiled vue

Comment: Well thats what I've tried to  do but I havent had any success. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong or I need to do something special because the way WP works. But putting the script link in the index file def doesnt work and I've enqueued it but I cant actually get it to interact with my page.